# What does philosophy say about the normativity of simulated thought within the analytical tradition?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-language, symbolic-logic, computation

Given the [coherence theory of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_theory_of_truth), new [propositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition) must observe previous theory and logic (i.e. every thinking step must be consistent with rules of logic); many [analytic philosophies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_philosophy) believe it is possible to write an effective procedure/algorithm which use current knowledge to produce new knowledge such as those philosophies that support [cognitive science](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/cognitive-science/).

My question is **'How do they advocate we best formalize [thinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought), and will this formalization guarantee the best possible thinking procedure (best in terms of ability to produce/discover new knowledge) in the lens of the [psychology of normative thinking](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/psychology-normative-cognition/)?**

I'm seeking answers to throw light on the [philosophy of knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology) (scientific or otherwise) and how computers automate reasoning effectively.

Comment: Perhaps your question could be better expressed as "How can we refine thinking?"  ...or perhaps, "What irreducible functions constitute thinking?"

Comment: @elliotsvensson That is the first question. Will defining the 'refining process' help?

Comment: I'm hoping for a restatement of the title question so that it's more likely for you to get, "what's the algorithm" -type answers instead of "you can't define yourself" -type answers.

Comment: Are you asking about the P vs NP problem?

Comment: @Richard can't see equivalence!

Comment: You might get just as far by posting your question at AI.stackexchenge.com.

Comment: Sorry, but these questions do not fit our format because they are are unanswerable as phrased. "Can we write an effective procedure/algorithm  to produce new results?" Anything produced by an algorithm is by definition not "new". "Can we define ingenuity? Can we formalize ideal thinking process?" are not so much questions as prompts for a forum discussion, we take question with more or less objective answer based on existing philosophical literature. "Throwing light on the nature of unknown" is more for poetry, and is a separate question from "functions".

Comment: @Conifold The purpose of question is to stimulate a discussion if ingenuity is actually derivable via algorithm. That is, is ingenuity actually new, or is ultimately a result of axioms. Of course, literal definition itself answers the question. The question is about questioning the preconceived notions about ingenuity, as far as problem solving/new discoveries is concerned.

Comment: We are a Q&A, discussions are off-topic on this site. You can try [The Philosophy Forum](https://thephilosophyforum.com/).

Comment: @Conifold *purpose is to stimulate philosophical answers on the question.

Comment: @Ajax read about Turing and the P vs NP problem. He tried to establish whether any arbitrary piece of code would error or not... It sounds like what you're asking.

Comment: [We are not doing philosophy here](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/friends-we-are-not-philosophers) either. Your purposes just do not fit this particular site, sorry.

Comment: @Richard I see your point. P vs NP is a formal version of my question.

Comment: @Ajax if you solve the problem you'll be rich and immortal. But Turing didn't and he was an actual and proper genius :)

Comment: @Richard Genius is a talent for producing something for which no determinate rule can be given, not a predisposition consisting of a skill for something that can be learned by following some rule or other.

— Immanuel Kant

Comment: @Ajax in order to do the things he did he needed to be an exceptional mathematician. There are lots of those who aren't geniuses. But most couldn't apply that skill the way Turing did. He was visionary. Up there with Descartes, Gauss, Laplace etc

Comment: @Community: What is the community that does not dare out itself? Borg, I don't like you Borg ...

Comment: Aristotle's dialectictal logic seems enough. I see no reason for any other and know of no case where abandoning it for some other logic has produced otherwise unavailable knowledge. There is also the issue that not all knowledge is an outcome of logical thinking. .   .

Comment: Edited to avoid the "opinion objection".